# Expected type '*http.Client.Request', found '*const http.Client.Request'

Tags: zig

Trying to make http GET request as:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    _ = gpa.deinit();

    var client: std.http.Client = .{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer client.deinit();

    // Parse the URI.
    const uri = std.Uri.parse("http://httpbin.org/get") catch unreachable;

    // Create the headers that will be sent to the server.
    var headers = std.http.Headers{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer headers.deinit();

    // Accept anything.
    try headers.append("accept", "*/*");
    try headers.append("accept", "application/json");

    if (client.request(.GET, uri, headers, .{})) |req| {
        defer req.deinit();
        try req.start();
        try req.wait();

        std.log.debug("status: {}", .{req.response.status});
    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("{any}", .{err});
    }

    //  try std.testing.expect(req.response.status == .ok);
}
```

But got the error:

```bash
main.zig:24:16: error: expected type '*http.Client.Request', found '*const http.Client.Request'
        try req.start();
            ~~~^~~~~~
main.zig:24:16: note: cast discards const qualifier
/usr/lib/zig/std/http/Client.zig:538:23: note: parameter type declared here
    pub fn start(req: *Request) StartError!void {
                      ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: please use learning resources before posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer, just need to copy it to a variable, now my running code is:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    defer if (gpa.deinit() != .ok) {
        // oh no, we've got a leak
        std.log.err("We got a leack", .{});
    } else {
        std.log.debug("memory managed correctly", .{});
    };

    var client: std.http.Client = .{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer client.deinit();

    // Parse the URI.
    const uri = std.Uri.parse("http://httpbin1.org/get") catch unreachable;

    // Create the headers that will be sent to the server.
    var headers = std.http.Headers{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer headers.deinit();

    // Accept anything.
    try headers.append("accept", "*/*");
    try headers.append("accept", "application/json");

    if (client.request(.GET, uri, headers, .{})) |const_req| {
        var req = const_req;
        defer req.deinit();
        try req.start();
        try req.wait();

        std.log.debug("status: {}", .{req.response.status});

    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("error: {}", .{err});
    }
}
```

And I got correctly the below output:

```
error: error: error.UnknownHostName
debug: memory managed correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

you must store request in a variable (`var`).

```rs
var req = client.request(.GET, uri, headers, .{}) catch |err| {
    std.log.err("{}\n", .{err});
    return err;
};

defer req.deinit();
try req.start();
try req.wait();
```

also call `gpa.deinit()` when you are done with allocator. usually before exiting.

```
+ defer _ = gpa.deinit();
- _ = gpa.deinit();
```

Comment: The problem with using `catch |err| { return err;}` is the program is existing upon getting this error, I need to capture the error without existing the program.